# Getting value of environment variable in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a properties file to set some environment variables say:

```
mydata.properties:

VAR1=Data1
VAR2=Data2
```

Now I want to define a new variable called VAR3 that can hold either VAR1 or VAR2 like:

```
mydata.properties:

VAR1=Data1
VAR2=Data2
VAR3=VAR2
```

To make these variables to be available to my bash session I am using this command

```
source mydata.properties
```

Now my requirement is to print the value for VAR3 so that it can print the internal data of the sourced VAR2 variable like:

```
Value of VAR3 is Data2
```

I tried different options like

`echo "Value of VAR3 is $$VAR3"`

This gives me junk output.

or `echo "Value of VAR3 is ${$VAR3}"`

This give me error as `Value of ${$VAR3}: bad substitution`

Please help me how to get this output.

Comment: "but I was getting errors." - **what** "errors"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really need to expand the variable that VAR3 points to (instead of just setting VAR3 to the value of VAR2 to begin with), you can use indirect variable expansion with `${!varname}`:

```
$ VAR1=Data1
$ VAR2=Data2
$ VAR3=VAR2
$ echo "${!VAR3}"
Data2
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't use bash, but

```
mydata.properties:

VAR1=Data1
VAR2=Data2
VAR3=$VAR2
```

should do it. Note the extra $ infront of var2 in the last line.

Comment: `echo "VAR3 is ${VAR3}"` wouldn't print `VAL3 is Data2`? How so? Is this a special property of bash properties files or general behavior?

Comment: that's not the `echo` code that's in the question -- what's in the question is `echo "VAR3 is $$VAR3"` or `echo "VAR3 is ${$VAR3}`.  The first of which gives a bad substitution error, and the second of which prints the value of `$` followed by literal `VAR3`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to get into the habit of doing it this way:

```
VAR3=${VAR2}
```

This is the same as `VAR3=$VAR2`, but when you are using variables embedded in other text (like `VAR3=${VAR2}_foo`), you will need the `{}`, so it's a good idea to use them by default.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
VAR2=$VAR3
```

then

```
echo "Value of VAR3 is $VAR3"
```

Note the single `$` in both places.  You use the `$` to reference the value of variables, so you need to use it when assigning the value of VAR2, and when printing its value in the echo command

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how to make a reference in BASH. The syntax can be rather tricky. It involves using `eval` and `echo` to be able to set the value:

```
VAR2=Data2
VAR3=VAR2   #Reference!

echo "The value of $VAR3 is $(eval echo \$$VAR3)"
```

It's better to use hash arrays instead of trying to use references directly:

```
REF[VAR3]=$VAR2

echo "The value of VAR3 = ${REF[VAR3]}"
```

Or, as others point out, you could have simply done this:

```
VAR3="$VAR2"
```

if you merely want to set `$VAR3` to be the same as `$VAR2`, and you don't care about references.