# Linux program only answers no even though a shell variable name exist

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote the following program to find valid shell variable names. I always get the answer as no when I run the program even if the shell variable exist. Here is the code:

```
if [ -n "$(echo $1 | grep "^[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*$")" ]
then
        echo yes
else
        echo no
fi
```

Comment: How do you invoke the program?  If you run `./program $PATH`, you will get `no` (except for extraordinarily uncommon and impractical values of `$PATH`); if you run `./program PATH`, you should get yes.

Comment: FYI, if your shell is bash (and your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`), there's no need to use `grep` here; you can (more efficiently) run regular expressions within the shell: `re='^[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*$'; if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`

Comment: Your title talks about whether checking whether a name "exists", whereas your code given checks for whether a name *is valid*, not whether a variable with that name _exists_. Perhaps you might clarify your actual goal between these (and how you expect this script to be started/run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `if [ -n "${!1}" ]` will do the trick. Call your program as follows:

```
./program JAVA_HOME
```

See this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550793/getting-value-of-environment-variable-in-unix) for more info.

Comment: if [ -n $1 ] gives an answer as yes to all questions & by replacing " " with ' ' still gives the answer as no